# Cannot access 'Blockchain' (class) before initialization at btnMineBlock

Tags: javascript

I have created a class Blockchain in JS and it has a function addBlock() which takes data(object) as a parameter , when I am trying to click submit button i am getting this error: **Cannot access 'Blockchain' before initialization at btnMineBlock**

here is my onclick function:
This is working fine when I m trying to do without frontend but whenever I m calling onclick function its creatig issue.

```
function btnMineBlock() {
    const blockchain = new Blockchain();
    const btnData = document.getElementById('dataBlock1').value;
    blockchain.addBlock({data:btnData});
    console.log(btnData);

    
console.log(blockchain);
}
```

this is my html code:

```
    <div class="block">
        <p id="timestamp">
            Timestamp:
        </p>
        <p id="data">
            Data:
        </p>
        <p id="nonce">
            Nonce:
        </p>
        <p id="hash">
            Hash:
        </p>
        <p id="prevHash">
            prevHash:
        </p>
        <input type="text" id="dataBlock1">
        <button type="submit" id="btn" onclick="btnMineBlock()">Mine Block</button>
    </div>
```

And following code is my Blockchain class

```
class Blockchain {
    constructor() {
        this.chain = [Block.genesis()];
    }
    addBlock({ data }) {
        const newBlock = Block.mineBlock({
            prevBlock: this.chain[this.chain.length - 1],
            data,
        })
        this.chain.push(newBlock);
    }

   
}
```

All other functions are imported from other diff files and they are working perfectly before btnMineBlock() function.

Comment: mistakely i forget to close a curly braces in the que... please consider it

Comment: Please include an [mre].  It's not possible to determine the problem given the code provided.

Comment: You can edit the question to add the `}` in its proper place. Also, where do you define the `Blockchain` class? I mean, where is its code relative to the `btnMineBlock()` function?

Comment: Error message appears to be self-explanatory: You haven't initialized `Blockchain`.

Comment: Now I edited the code ...hope it will make sense and note: I have intialize the Blockchain() class and btnMineBlock() function in same file

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in the HTML that imports the definitions of `btnMineBlock` and `Blockchain`.

Comment: lets forget about the html and btnMineBlock() function , when I m trying to run and conosole.log() it then its perfectly returning the objects with all data, But the issue is created only when i m trying to call it inside btnMineBlock()...

Comment: Is `Blockchain` defined when `btnMineBlock` runs? `console.log(Blockchain)` will tell you.

Comment: it still showing the same error after running console.log(Blockchain)

Comment: You run `btnMineBlock` before `Blockchain`, closing

Comment: Running `console.log(Blockchain)` is not for fixing the problem. It's for diagnosing the problem. Did it log a function? Or did it log `undefined`? And you need to do it before the error occurs, because once the error occurs, execution stops and your `console.log()` never executes.